# log4net maximum rolling count

Tags: c#, log4net, rollingfileappender

while configuring the Rollingfileappender for my logfile in a C# Project I am wondering what is the maximum number of the rolling count.

I configured the countDirection param with a value >= 0 which means that the backup logs are not rolled over and the count is constantly increasing no matter what I set as a limit for param maxSizeRollBackups or maxBackupIndex.

These two parameters are giving limitation to the count of files existing in my directory but not the rolling index in the filename (log.1, log.2, ....log.30) The documentation of RollingFileappender says [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.CountDirection.html):

> CountDirection >= 0 does the opposite i.e. log.1 is the first backup
>   made, log.5 is the 5th backup made, etc. For infinite backups use
>   CountDirection >= 0 to reduce rollover costs.

Does anybody know if there is a maximum limit of the rolling count or is it counting until the datatype overflows?

Comment: As your quote says, _"For **infinite** backups use CountDirection >= 0 to reduce rollover costs."_. If you really want the details, have a [look at the source](https://github.com/apache/log4net/blob/trunk/src/Appender/RollingFileAppender.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit would be about Max int (2,147,483,647), so you can have a lot of backups. You should limit the amount of backups with the MaxSizeRollBackups.